# TYPO3 8, Form extension - best practice for custom yaml files

Tags: forms, typo3

When generating forms with the form module the corresponding yaml files get stored in fileadmin/user_upload.

Now I want to integrate those yaml files into my sitepackage and thus into my CVS. Where is the correct place for them? In the example extension they are stored in `Resources/...` while I would think they have to go into `Configuration/Yaml`

And how do I configure the form extension to search them in that place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's basically a matter of taste where *exactly* one saves his form definitions, I try to separate **form configuration** and **form definitions**.

From the official documentation:

> [...] the **form configuration** allows you to define:
>
> - which form elements, finishers, and validators are available,
> - how those objects are pre-configured,
> - how those objects will be displayed within the frontend and backend.
>
> In contrast, the **form definition** describes the specific form,
>   including
>
> - all form elements and their corresponding validators,
> - the order of the form elements within the form, and
> - the finishers which are fired as soon as the form has been submitted.
> - Furthermore, it defines the concrete values of each property of the mentioned aspects.

So, for more clarity I save all form configuration in a sitepackage under `Configuration/Yaml/` and the form definitions under `Resources/Private/Forms`, neighbouring the templates.

I [wrote a full tutorial](http://www.sklein-medien.de/en/tutorials/detail/assign-custom-templates-to-the-new-extform-framework/) how to use custom templates with EXT:form, which also includes the answers to your question.

In short:

**Register YAML configuration with TypoScript in your extension root folder as ext_typoscript_setup.txt (as recommended<sup>1</sup>)**

```
plugin.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
  100 = EXT:my_extension/Configuration/Yaml/CustomFormSetup.yaml
}

module.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
  100 = EXT:my_extension/Configuration/Yaml/CustomFormSetup.yaml
}
```

**CustomFormSetup.yaml – setting up a new storage path**

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      persistenceManager:
        allowedExtensionPaths:
          10: EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Forms/
        allowSaveToExtensionPaths: true
        allowDeleteFromExtensionPaths: true
```

<sup>1</sup>TypoScript inside an `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` is automatically loaded in both frontend and backend of your TYPO3 installation **directly after installing your extension**. This differs from other TypoScript files, which have to be included manually, e.g. as static templates. See [official Form Framework documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/8.7/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#yaml-registration-for-the-backend-via-ext-typoscript-setup-txt).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I decided to store the YAML files in the `Configuration/Yaml` directory. But I made two subdirectories: `FormConfiguration` and `FormDefinition`. For me this seems to be more logic.

Comment: In "form configuration", "form" refers to the `Form Framework`, while in "form definition", "form" refers to `a SPECIFIC form`. Therefore, the locations `Configuration/Yaml/` and `Resources/Private/Forms` make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `Resources/Private/Forms` for your form definitions. The form extension clarifies how to [register additional form definition paths](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/latest/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#yaml-registration-for-the-frontend).